# Footer not extending with bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with putting together my page based on my design with Bootstrap. I will provide the following html code and see if someone can help me understand why my footer isn't the full width of the page and why my purple box class is.

[image]

If you can review my html code and see if you can explain to me also why my image under Lessons isn't the full width as well because I set it to 100% width which I was understanding does it compared to its parent container which would be the div with a class of container.

Link to actual dev site page. [Dev Lessons Site Page](http://dev.cassandradavidsonflautist.com/lessons.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="A great site to hear the musical talents of Cassandra Davidson and also to promote her as a private instructor.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="music, teacher, lessons, weddings, church">
        <meta name="author" content="Jeffrey Davidson">
        <title>Cassandra Davidson Studio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <header>
                <h1>Cassandra Davidson Studio</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="lessons.html">Lessons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="recordings.html">Recordings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <h2>Lessons</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <img src="assets/images/music-staff.png" alt="Music staff">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h3>About Your Lessons</h3>
                    <p>Lessons are face to face once a week for 30 minutes or 60 minutes.  Times based on age, and level of interest.  Lessons are given for students to gain knowledge of the flute.  They will learn flute techniques, musicality, and standard flute works.  Students will learn to perform for others and gain confidence in themselves and their playing.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Practice</h3>
                    <p>Students are expected to practice every day.  Students in a 30 minute lessons should be practicing for at least 30 minutes every day, while students in 60 minute lessons should be practicing for at least 60 minutes.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Materials</h3>
                    <p>Student should bring with them to lessons books decided by the instructor at their first lesson, and a spiral notebook.  There may be more needs as the student moves on in lessons.  These book will include, a tone book, technique book, etude book and solo material.  For beginning students they should also bring the book being used in their band class.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Recitals</h3>
                    <p>The studio will give at least two recitals throughout the year.  Students are expected to play for these recitals and stay to listen to their peers.  If a student needs to miss, there will need to be approval beforehand.  Recitals are a good opportunity for students to learn from others and to hear different pieces of music.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Masterclasses</h3>
                    <p>The studio will provide a masterclass situation about three times a year.  This may be all students of the same age together in a joint lesson with the teacher, bringing in another instructor to give feedback, or a few students playing solo and getting feedback from the other students as well as the instructor.  The students are expected to attend these classes, so they can benefit from hearing other students, playing with students, and getting feedback from another source.</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Payment</h3>
                    <p>Payment is due at the beginning of every month, for the entire month.   The cost is $25 per lesson for 30 minute lessons and $50 per lesson for 60 minute lessons.  This cost includes all expenses for the recitals and masterclasses, so there are no extra fees for those events.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="assets/images/girl-playing-piano.png" alt="Girl looking at camera while playing piano.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 purple-box">
                    <h3>Cancellation/Make-up</h3>
                    <p>If a student cannot attend lessons for any reason, please call the instructor as soon as possible.  If possible at the beginning of each month, let the instructor know if the students cannot attend any lesson that month.  If the instructor receives at least 24 hour notice than there will be a make-up lesson scheduled if possible or a credit for the next month.  Make-up lessons are always preferred and the use of a credit should only be used if a make-up lesson cannot be scheduled because of conflicts.  If a student does not show up for a lesson without notifying the instructor there will be no make-up lesson or credit.  If the instructor must miss for any reason, they will contact the students as soon as possible and schedule a make-up lesson or give a credit.</p>
                </div>  
            </div>  
            <footer>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>&copy; 2015 Jeffrey Davidson</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </footer>
        </div>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your markup.

The `row` class provides negative margin (-15px) left and right, so that the columns appear properly within them.

The `col` class elements have 15px padding left and right to provide spacing "internally", but this causes the 15px of space on the left / right edge, which is why the `row` column has negative margin.

The `div.row` inside of `footer` was unnecessary, and causing the extra space.

```
<footer class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>&copy; 2015 Jeffrey Davidson</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**As for the image**, it does not have any styles on it, therefore it is not filling the full width.  (I've inspected your live site using browser inspector, and there are definitely no styles on it).

Give it a class, or apply styles directly, so that:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* without this, the image will skew */
}
```

**Lastly, for your left / right spacing** after thinking this through, in order for this to be responsive, your best bet is to use some markup / css to provide a "max width" on the spaces.  If you used padding, you'd have to adjust the padding at each media query / kick, where really what you are after is some space at the larger desktop sizes.

Personally, for clarity, I like to create a div called "liner" or similar, like so:

```
<footer class="row">
    <div class="liner">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>&copy; 2015 Jeffrey Davidson</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Then, give that liner some css like so:

```
div.liner {
    margin: 0 auto; /* auto ensures it will stay centered */
    padding: 0; /* may or may not be necessary depending on your resets */
    max-width: 1000px; /* or whatever your desired max width is */
}
```

Add this `.liner` to your header, footer, and your main content area, and you will get the desired effect.

Comment: Oh wow I thought I had the width set as 100% maybe I removed it during testing for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: Now if you notice all of the main content on the design I made was in about a total of 130px on that 1200px design. On my 27 inch it doesn't do that. Can you explain why that is for me to understand?

Comment: Which part is 130px? I'm looking in the main content - are you talking about the column widths? Sorry, I'm not sure which part you are referring to.  Happy to look / help if you can clarify.

Comment: I've used the bootstrap template inside Adobe Illustrator where I created the design and my artboard is 1200px wide and from the left and right side all content is inside a container that has 130px padding on the left and ride side. I hope that this makes sense to you.

Comment: Ah.  Got it.  In your image, everything has a "max width"which holds it in from the edges about 130px.  Are you looking for that 130px to stay constant, or for the page to never get wider than that?  (It's hard to know what Illustrator did to add that, but Bootstrap doesn't do that automatically, it would be some classes / markup you would have to add)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the image. But all of the content is enclosed 130px on both sides from a bootstrap template that was brought in to be used in AI. Technically the columns are 120 wide with a 10px gutter so that makes up the 130. I could post another image to help further explain what I mean if need be.

Comment: I'm not sure about if the page will ever get wider than that. I was just basing it initially off that design so I'm not even sure if I should really be using the col-xs-x or be using the col-lg-x for the classes since that's what I'm testing off of right now.

Comment: Thoughts to this @cale_b

Comment: I've edited the answer to address your 130px question.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can handle the navigation so that it aligns to the right and inline with my h1 using the bootstrap classes. I tried this but not getting successful.

Comment: Sure, there's several ways.  Add a class of `col-sm-4` to your h1, and `col-sm-8` to your nav (and probably also a class of `text-right` to your nav).  You may need to play with the classes (may not be col-sm-4 you want, but col-sm-5, for example, in which case you'd adjust your nav to be col-sm-7).  All "col" numbers in a row must add up to less than or equal to 12 in order to show on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Add row class for footer and remove it for div inside (then you can safely remove that div):

```
<footer class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>&copy; 2015 Jeffrey Davidson</p>
        </div>
</footer>
```

To match your page look to an image further you can add some padding to <p> in a footer:

```
footer p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Just adjust padding value to get desired effect.

Comment: What about the image?

Comment: Yeah, that's not explaining why the image is not full width.  Read the question again a bit more carefully.

Comment: Please do because I'm confused here.